# Using SVG Filter Gaussian blur with single page app (Ember)

Tags: ember.js, svg, d3.js, svg-filters

I'm trying to use d3 to apply a Gaussian blur to an svg circle while on a non-home page of my SPA with Ember.

First I tried using the d3 code

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var svg = d3.select('#svg');
    var filter = svg
    .append("filter")
      .attr("id", "blur")
    .append("feGaussianBlur")
      .attr('in', 'SourceAlpha')
      .attr("stdDeviation", 3)
      .attr('result', 'blur');

    svg.append('circle')
         .attr('cx', 50)
         .attr('cy', 50)
         .attr('r', 20)
         .style({'fill': 'blue'})
         .attr('class', 'cursor')
         .attr('filter', 'url(#blur)');
}
```

but that didn't work. I then tried the example from the mozilla docs,

```
<svg width="230" height="120"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <filter id="blurMe">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter>

  <circle cx="60"  cy="60" r="50" fill="green" />

  <circle cx="170" cy="60" r="50" fill="green"
          filter="url(#blurMe)" />
</svg>
```

Inserted directly into the handlebars template. That didn't work either. Note this has all been on the BridgeBuilderView page.

Then I redid all of that on the index.hbs page that is loaded first when the application starts. When I do that the gaussian blurs work in both cases. I was wondering if anyone has some insight into why this is the case, and how I can get it to work on my non-root page.

Thanks

Comment: In the d3, at least, you forgot your defs element. Try something that already works: http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/raw/5200394/dropshadow.js and see if there's a problem in not-this-code.

Comment: Does your website design involve a `<base>` tag in your HTML?  That frequently causes problems with SVG + template-based web sites.  The problem is that the URL in the `<base>` gets appended to the URL fragment in your style properties or use elements.  E.g. `filter="url(#blurMe)"` becomes `filter="url(//some.other.page#blurMe)"`.

Comment: I had the defs container originally and removed it to see whether that would help. I tried that sample code and it didn't work. Note that the code I posted **did** work on my index.hbs but not my bridge-builder.hbs which is why I believe it is a SPA problem.

Comment: @AmeliaBR is right. I'm using Ember CLI and they automatically insert a base tag. I found this github issue https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2633 on addressing the problem.Unfortunately at the moment fixing the problem by removing the <base href="/"> tag also makes it impossible to load from any url other than root.

Comment: You could use an absolute URL for the blur e.g. url(http://somewhere.com#blurMe)

Comment: @RobertLongson Worth mentioning that the absolute URL has to end up pointing back to the page you're on.  Last I checked, Firefox is the only browser that allows you to load style resources (like gradients, filters, etc.) from external files.  It's possible CSS filters will improve the support, but it isn't something I'd count on just yet.